# civicrm entity multilanguage

Tags: language

I have converted a civicrm campaign into a drupal entity with the civicrm entity contributed module but it does not allow me to activate the translation of the content entity, I cannot find the configuration, I have the drupal in multilanguage and the civicrm is also translated. Use drupal 10 and civicrm 5.69.5 version